# Not able to display dashboard in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, dashboard, report-chart

**My VisualForce Page Test Code for displaying dashboard -**

Code Snippet - Used (Apex:Iframe)

[image]

**After Clicking on Preview Button In Apex Page-**

[image]

**Error In Console**
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to embed a Salesforce public site into Visualforce page. To allow the embed you need to perform some setup:

- Go to: Setup > Develop > Sites. Click on Edit
- Set the value "Clickjack Protection Level" to "Allow framing by any page"

In case you are trying to do the reverse, you may want to look for "Clickjack Settings"

Comment: Still same issue's are showing in console. 

**Error 1 in Console**  

'https://nirmallya2016-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/01Z280000006Md4?isdtp=vw' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN

**Error 2 In Console** <br>

Uncaught SecurityError: Sandbox access violation: Blocked a frame at "https://nirmallya2016-dev-ed--c.ap2.visual.force.com" from accessing a frame at "null".  The frame being accessed is sandboxed and lacks the "allow-same-origin" flag. @San Tosh